# Lag when scrolling recyclerview

Tags: java, android

This is my adapters code:

```
public class CatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<CatModel> objects_;
Context context;
Class res = R.drawable.class;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView cat_text,cat_des;
    ImageView cat_img;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        cat_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cat_txt);
        cat_des = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cat_des);
        cat_img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cat_img);
    }
}

public CatAdapter(ArrayList<CatModel> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    objects_ = arrayList;
}

@Override
public CatAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cat_list_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.cat_text.setText(objects_.get(position).txt);
    holder.cat_des.setText(objects_.get(position).des);
    try {
        Field field = res.getField(objects_.get(position).img);
        int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
        holder.cat_img.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objects_.size();
}
}
```

`CatModel` class

```
public class CatModel {
    public String txt,img,des;
}
```

`CatModel.img` is id of my `drawables` that I put them in `R.strings`.
All of my items int `arraylist` is about 20 items and my `drawables` are optimized `SVG` that I converted into vector drawable. but when I'm scrolling it's not smooth. What can I do to optimize it?

Comment: You are using reflection in your onBindViewHolder. That's known to be slow, refactor your code to avoid reflection.

Comment: Can you explain more? @Francesc

Comment: You are using reflection on the res object (getField). Reflection is inherently slow and is probably pushing you over the 16ms barrier. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but you should be able to create a list or hashmap for your drawables and then link a drawable to the position using that list or hashmap.

Comment: excuse me im newbie to android i want to get drawables from resource so i found that way to do dynamically. can you post code? @Francesc

Comment: Please post more info on what the drawables are and how they are associated to the position so I have a better understanding on what you are trying to do. I need to know what the drawables are and what's in the objects_ object. Post the CatModel object as well.

Comment: i've edited my post @Francesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access your drawables using the resources directly, instead of reflection.

You should place your drawables in the respective "drawables" folder (drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and so on). Then in your object you reference the int associated with each drawable:

```
public class CatModel {
    public String txt,des;
    public int drawable;
}
```

where the drawable is one of your drawables, like

```
CatModel catModel = new CatModel();
catModel.drawable = R.drawable.my_drawable_1;
```

and so on.

Then in your adapter you use it like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.cat_text.setText(objects_.get(position).txt);
    holder.cat_des.setText(objects_.get(position).des);
    holder.img.setImageResource(objects_.get(position).drawable);
}
```

Comment: Why didn't i think of that! can i get drawables int from values?

Comment: Yes,  use the int value associated to each drawable through the R class.

Comment: In that case you'll need to use SysTrace to figure out what's blocking the UI, but the code here should not be causing any lag.